# Passing an array in data section of select2 jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, jquery-select2

i have a problem with the Select2 jquery plugin (with MVC3, Razor and Knockout JS) and a custom parameter that i want to pass to my ajax call.

I have this code:

```
$('#QuickSearchPresentation').select2({
        placeholder: "Search for a movie",
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
            url: '@Url.Action("QuickSearchMainContainerFromPresentationByIdFolders", "DataCenter", new { amount = 10 })',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            quietMillis: 400,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return ko.toJSON({
                    term: term,
                    idFolders: vm.Container.Catalogs
                });
            },
            results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
                console.log('results', data);
                return {results: data};
            }
        },
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {

            console.log('element', element);

        },
        formatResult: containerQuickSearchResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        formatSelection: containerQuickSearchResult,  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
    });
```

vm is my model from knockout js, and Catalogs its an array of int's.

The thing is that i cant pass the idFolders array to the Action on my server, the servers responds with a ""Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source" (because the array gets null on the Action in my Controller).
I try every possible way i think and i cant find the right way.

I hope you can help me with that.

Thanks,
Gonzalo.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery ajax call, for your data property try wrapping it in JSON.stringify(). Like this:

```
data: function (term, page) {
    return JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON({
        term: term,
        idFolders: vm.Container.Catalogs
    }));
},
```

I've noticed that wrapping data with JSON.stringify makes MVC handle the JSON correctly.